# Trying to add files that contain .stl to a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `ZipArchive` that has a bunch of files in it. I am trying to get all the files that have the file format `.stl` but I cant seem to get it right.

Here is what I have:

```
var scan = import.ZipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.Name == string.Format("*.stl").ToList());
```

I am sure that I am missing something silly, but I keep getting the error:

```
operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 
'system.collections.generic.list<char>'
```

Would anyone be able to help me out?

Comment: You have misplaced `()`. It should be: `var scan = import.ZipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.Name == string.Format("*.stl")).ToList();`, But you will get a `List<bool>` back, you probably need `Where`. Also your comparison will not work. You need to compare extension, use `Path.GetExtension` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
var scan = import.ZipFile.Entries
                    .Where(e => Path.GetExtension(e.Name).Equals(".stl", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    .ToList();
```

You have misplaced (). That is causing a comparison between string and a list of characters as, `<string>.ToList` will return a `List<char>`.  It could be:

```
var scan = import.ZipFile.Entries.Any(e => e.Name == string.Format("*.stl")).ToList();
```

**But** you will get a `List<bool>` back, you  need `Enumerable.Where` clause.

**More importantly,** your comparison `e.Name == string.Format("*.stl")` will not work. You need to compare extension, use [`Path.GetExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Your comparison is using wild cards which is used by `Directory.GetFiles` or on command prompt, but you can't use that on `string` comparison in C#.

Comment: how you know Entries are List<string> ?

Comment: Thank you. I ended up just figuring this out for myself looking through the linq documentation. I arrived at a similar answre, but this was closest to what i used which was `var scan = import.ZipFile.Entries.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(".stl")).ToList();`. Thanks again!

Comment: @scapegoat17, great that you spend time with the documentation, it is always helpful. I guess you probably know that `Contains` would return files such as `a.stl.zip` matching the criteria. That is why use `Path.GetExtension` to get file path and then compare it *(ignoring case)*

Comment: @Habib - you are correct. I did not think of that and was just trying to get the error to go away :). changed my code to `var scan = import.ZipFile.Entries.Where(e => Path.GetExtension(e.Name).Equals(".stl")).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

`Any` returns a boolean value - i guess you want to get the list of all items?

```
var scan = import.ZipFile.Entries.Where(e => e.Name.EndsWith(".stl", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```